# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no kdu_jni in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, jai, geotools

I am trying to use GeoTiff to read TIFF file and I am having following warnings which lead to error.

> Jul 29, 2016 12:53:41 PM it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL
>   WARNING: Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path
>   Jul 29, 2016 12:53:41 PM it.geosolutions.util.KakaduUtilities loadKakadu
>   WARNING: Failed to load the Kakadu native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the Kakadu plugin: it won't be enabled. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no kdu_jni in java.library.path

How to solve this? I am using Eclipse and set Geotif path already in

```
 -Djava.libarary.path=E:/geotools-14.4-bin/geotools-14.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common reasons why you get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` are:

1. The native libraries that you are trying to load are not found. Does the directory `E:/geotools-14.4-bin/geotools-14.4` contain the libraries `gdaljni.dll` and `kdu_jni.dll`?
2. There is a mismatch of the "bitness" of your JVM and the native libraries: you are using 32-bit Java and the libraries are 64-bit or vice versa. Make sure that you use 64-bit Java if the libraries are 64-bit or vice versa.

Did you make a typo? It should be `java.library.path` and not `java.libarary.path` (you misspelled "library").

Comment: I downloaded GeoTools 14.2 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/files/GeoTools%2014%20Releases/14.4/geotools-14.4-bin.zip/download And it does not contain this dll files!! Where can I download 32-bit dlls for windows?

Comment: I don't know, you;'ll have to do some research; doesn't the documentation of GeoTools say something about this? Or look at http://www.gdal.org/ or Google for these DLLs to find out where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `kdu_jni.dll` in E:/geotools-14.4-bin/geotools-14.4 ? If so, set E:/geotools-14.4-bin/geotools-14.4 in Windows system environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: Actually that folder does not contain any dlls. Where should i download them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download from this link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/